# How do I make the node compiler work with these two operations of fs?

Tags: node.js

`fs.rename("${nombreHtml}.html",(err)=>{
                console.log(err)
            })
fs.appendFileSync("${nombreHtml}.html", htmlSeparado, () => { })`

I try to run these two operations but it doesn't want to work

Answer (score 1):

`fs.rename` is an **asyncronous** task.

By the time `fs.rename` finished its execution, `fs.appendFileSync` has already tried appending data to an html file which has not existed by the time.

1. `fs.rename` ... awaiting callback
2. `fs.append` ... failing
3. `fs.rename` finished, file now has a new name.

You probably want to either place `fs.appendFileSync` inside the `fs.rename` callback, or switch to promises. (example at the bottom)
example that should work:

```
fs.rename("${nombreHtml}.html",(err)=>{
  if (err) console.log(err)
  else {
    fs.appendFileSync("${nombreHtml}.html", htmlSeparado, () => { })
  }
})
```

By the way, because syncronous functions block the event loop and hence freeze your server for the time handling that function, making it unavailable for any other request - using `filesystem`'s syncronous functions is rather less recommended for the general usecase, as the read/write/append operations are rather long. it is recommended to use the async versions of them, which return a callback or a promise, as you have done using `fs.rename`.

`fs` has a built-in sub-module with the same functions as promises which can be accessed by `require('fs').promises`.

this way you could just

```
const { rename, appendFile } = require('fs').promises;

try {
  await rename("${nombreHtml}.html");
  await appendFile("${nombreHtml}.html", htmlSeparado);
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want a template string so that the variables insert themselves into the string:

```
fs.rename(`${nombreHtml}.html`,(err)=>{
                console.log(err)
            })
fs.appendFileSync(`${nombreHtml}.html`, htmlSeparado, () => { })
```

Comment: it didn't work

what I want is to delete this file with the same name so that the file can be updated later